# Integrate ZXing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

I'll start explaining all the steps I have done and in the end what is the problem.

1. Download ZXing-2.2 https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list
2. Extrac all in zxing-2.2.
3. Download and install Apache Ant http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJmndRfb1TU
4. With the use of Windows Commandline (Run->CMD) navigate to the extracted directory
5. In the commandline window - Type 'ant -f core/build.xml' press enter and let Apache work it's magic

At this moment is like [Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)

But Wooops, "Buildfile: core\build.xml does not exists! Build failed. ok. 
6. [Importing ZXing - missing core/build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857294/importing-zxing-missing-core-build-xml)

Now yes, i have my core.jar.

7. Open Android Studio, File -> Import Project -> Select /android/ in /zxing-2.2/ -> Create project from existing sources -> Project name: andoid -> Source files for... all checked Next -> Libraries (cant do nothing) Next -> Modules (android checked) Next -> SDK 1.7 Next -> Finish

With Project Open -> Build -> Rebuild project

100 errors
19 warnings

File -> project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> Java -> Select core.jar that i create before and OK -> Library 'core' will be added to the selected modules. (android) OK -> And OK in the Project Structure Dialog.

Build -> Rebuild Project

15 errors
20 warnings

All errors are error: constant expression required and 
I see [Error in Switch cases of ZXing project in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226941/error-in-switch-cases-of-zxing-project-in-android) 
I change all switchs for if elses.

0 errors
20 warnings

Ok, now continue:

File -> New project -> zxing_demo Next -> Next -> Blank Activity Next -> Finish

In new project -> File -> Import module -> Search and select /android/ OK -> Create module from existing sources Next ->  Next -> Next -> Next -> Finish

Now I can see in the explorer /android/ /zging_demoProject/ and External Libraries

Now i change my code tu scan QR

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zxing_demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.zxing_demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.zxing_demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}

}
```

Now test, Run -> Debug

And CRASH.

Logcat

```
08-31 02:58:28.085  20665-20665/com.example.zxing_demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zxing_demo/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
    ... 11 more
```

I can see in AndroidManifest.xml in this line

```
android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
```

"CaptureActivity" in red and the error say: Cannot resolve symbol 'CaptureActivity'

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> zxing_demo -> Dependencies -> Add -> Module dependency -> android OK -> Apply and OK

Now CaptureActivity looks good

Debug again

```
08-31 03:06:58.513  21740-21740/com.example.zxing_demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zxing_demo/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
    ... 11 more
```

I think I will use the application and intents, but now I want do this work, if someone now whats happen tell me please.

Comment: This question has a lot of views so just in case it helps anyone [here's my very similar problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334572/android-studio-0-3-2-and-zxing

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I was integrating ZXING into an Android application and there were no good sources for the input all over, I will give you a hint on what worked for me - **because it turned out to be very easy**.

There is a real handy git repository that provides the `zxing` android library project as an AAR archive.

- https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

All you have to do is add this to your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
}
```

and Gradle does all the magic to compile the code and makes it accessible in your app.

To start the Scanner afterwards, use this class/method:
From the Activity:

```
new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Activity
```

From a Fragment:

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Fragment
// If you're using the support library, use IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this) instead.
```

There are several customizing options:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

They have a **[sample-project](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/sample)** and are providing several integration examples:

- [AnyOrientationCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.java)
- [ContinuousCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)
- [CustomScannerActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/CustomScannerActivity.java)
- [ToolbarCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ToolbarCaptureActivity.java)

If you already visited the link you going to see that I just copy&pasted the code from the git README. If not, go there to get some more insight and code examples.

Comment: Huge help. I had spent over a day trying to import Zxing from another project and was getting nowhere. Then I found this link and *BAM* it's done. Just follow the code example as above from this link: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent.

Comment: Code Works !! I have one issue , I want scanner portrait and need to do add custom layout for scanning screen 
Can any one tell me how to achieve ??

Comment: To change the orientation, create a new Activity extending CaptureActivity, and specify the orientation in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: When trying run my app using ContinuousCapture in Fragment:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @pjdupreez read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239699/zxing-on-android-pdf417

Comment: @Langusten thanks. I have seen this post before, but could never get the IntentIntegrator to do the scan as fast as with the Barcode Scanner App from ZXing. any idea why it would not scan immediately?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working with the ZXing Barcode Scanner. Just for interest: I am using a framework that uses support.v4 fragments. I call initiateScan() from my fragment. The Activity's onActivityResult gets fired and not the fragments. I simply get the fragment from the Activity's onActivityResult using supportFragmentManager and call it's onActivity's result. Probably not the best way to do it, maybe a bit of a hack, but it something.

Comment: @LangustenGustel does this work without requiring a barcode app to be installed ? I implemented ZXing in a previous app where I converted it to work without requiring third party scanner apps to be installed. Just want to know if this works without having a scanner app installed, before I try to import my old code.

Comment: @Janpan; yes it does!

Comment: @LangustenGustel that is super awesome man ! Thanks ! My old android app was done in netbeans and the past year I have been working in android studio and gradle projects so this is a relief. Will try it out tomorrow and upvote, thx !

Comment: This's not an original ZXing library, it's a `journeyapp` implementation!

Answer (score 8):

Anybody facing the same issues, follow the simple steps:

Import the project `android` from downloaded `zxing-master` zip file using option `Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` and add the dollowing 2 lines of codes in your app level `build.gradle` file and and you are ready to run.

So simple, yahh...

```
dependencies {
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core
        compile group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'core', version: '3.2.1'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/android-core
        compile group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'android-core', version: '3.2.0'

    }
```

You can always find latest version `core` and `android core` from below links:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.2.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/android-core/3.2.0

UPDATE (29.05.2019)

Add these dependencies instead:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Perefct simple answer :) After Many R&D i found this link , and it looks like a magic is happened.

Comment: now Latest version Core and Android Core is
      dependencies {
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core
        implementation group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'core', version: '3.3.2'

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/android-core
        implementation group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'android-core', version: '3.3.0'

    }

Comment: i want to merge this in already made project not want to import as new project, so how can i achieve this ? urgent help required :)

Comment: Thanks! I also had to import the project and add dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

```
buttion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator(Fragment.this).initiateScan();
            }
        });

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }



dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**From version 4.x, only Android SDK 24+ is supported by default, and androidx is required.**

Add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' // Older versions may give compile errors
}
```

**Older SDK versions**

For Android SDK versions < 24, you can downgrade zxing:core to 3.3.0 or earlier for Android 14+ support:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
```

You'll also need this in your Android manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />
```

Source : https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Answer (score -1):

this tutorial help me to integrate to android studio:
http://wahidgazzah.olympe.in/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/
if down try [THIS](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:77j1zOPrmeoJ%3awahidgazzah.olympe.in/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/%20&cd=1&hl=es-419&ct=clnk&gl=co&client=firefox-a)

just add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
         android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Hope this help!.

Comment: That did not help

Comment: @deepakgates : outdated, can you bring some code to check?