# Android Studio (0.3.2) and ZXing

Tags: jar, android-studio, zxing

I cannot get ZXing to work in Android Studio. I have generated the core.jar file using Ant, and the same jar worked fine using Eclipse. Now I must get it working in Android Studio (0.3.2).

Here is what I have tried but to no avail so far:

- Copy the core.jar file into the PROJECTNAMEProject/PROJECTNAME/libs/
- Right click > Add as library
- Choose Project Library as the 'Level' in
  the Create Library dialog, with 'Add to module' set to the
  PROJECTNAME folder. I have tried the Global and Module library types
  as well as Project library.
- Add `compile files('libs/core.jar')` to
  the dependencies section of the
  PROJECTNAMEProject/PROJECTNAME/build.gradle

The error I'm getting seems to be telling me I'm including the jar twice:

Gradle: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Gradle: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `compile files('libs/core.jar')` to `build.gradle`, the only other thing you should need to do is click the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button in the toolbar.

Comment: Ah okay so I was adding it twice by having that gradle line and 'Adding as library'. Interestingly before I saw this answer I upgraded to 0.3.6 to see if it would help and that context option is gone entirely from the jar. Thanks for your assistance - for anyone else struggling just drag the jar into the libs folder and stick in that line then hit 'rebuild' or 'sync project with gradle files'.