# ZXing in portrait mode native android app

Tags: android, zxing

I made Zxing work in my app using the method described in the answer here, using minimal zxing:

[Integrate ZXing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio/23788163#23788163)

But now I am trying to figure out how to display the scanning in portrait mode?

Everything I have found involves modifying the code for Zxing and the method i'm using i don't have access to that code