# Importing ZXing project into Android Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android, zxing

I am very new to Android development. I just setup the environment and using Android Studio. 
As described in;

[Integrate ZXing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio)

I had imported ZXing-2.3.0 project into Android Studio and added core-3.1.0.jar as a library to the project but I still get the below error messages when tried to build project. What could be the problem?

```
> Information:Using javac 1.7.0_65 to compile java sources
> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'main5'
> Information:Compilation completed with 53 errors and 0 warnings in 15
> sec Information:53 errors Information:0 warnings
> /home/korhan/Android/libraries/zxing-2.3.0/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java
> Error:(26, 19) java: package android.app does not exist Error:(27, 19)
> java: package android.app does not exist Error:(28, 23) java: package
> android.content does not exist Error:(29, 23) java: package
> android.content does not exist Error:(30, 23) java: package
> android.content does not exist Error:(31, 26) java: package
> android.content.pm does not exist Error:(32, 26) java: package
> android.content.pm does not exist Error:(33, 19) java: package
> android.net does not exist Error:(34, 18) java: package android.os
> does not exist Error:(35, 20) java: package android.util does not
> exist Error:(141, 17) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
> Activity   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(149, 27)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Activity   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(233, 16)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AlertDialog   location:
> class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(245, 16) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AlertDialog
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(283, 41) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(287, 39) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(300, 44) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ResolveInfo
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(310, 11) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AlertDialog
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(351, 83) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(376, 16) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AlertDialog
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(389, 16) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AlertDialog
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(411, 33) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(246, 5) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(246, 29) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(247, 28) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(267, 25) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(268, 25) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent  
> location: class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(288, 5) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
> PackageManager   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(289, 10)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ResolveInfo   location:
> class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(289, 72) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable
> PackageManager   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(301, 10)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ResolveInfo   location:
> class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> Error:(311, 16) java: package AlertDialog does not exist Error:(311,
> 57) java: package AlertDialog does not exist Error:(314, 68) java:
> package DialogInterface does not exist Error:(335, 67) java: package
> DialogInterface does not exist Error:(353, 25) java: cannot find
> symbol   symbol:   variable Activity   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(390, 5)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(390, 25)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(391, 24)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(400, 21)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(401, 21)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Intent   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(426, 35)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Bundle   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator Error:(427, 31)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Bundle   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
> /home/korhan/Android/libraries/zxing-2.3.0/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegratorV30.java
> Error:(19, 19) java: package android.app does not exist Error:(20, 23)
> java: package android.content does not exist Error:(29, 17) java:
> cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Fragment   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30 Error:(34,
> 30) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Fragment   location:
> class com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30
> Error:(40, 41) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30
> /home/korhan/Android/libraries/zxing-2.3.0/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegratorSupportV4.java
> Error:(18, 23) java: package android.content does not exist Error:(19,
> 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist Error:(28, 17)
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Fragment   location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorSupportV4
> Error:(33, 36) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Fragment  
> location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorSupportV4
> Error:(39, 41) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Intent  
> location: class
> com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorSupportV4
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are very old instructions. The project docs may be of much more help. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing  You should be using a recent version, not 2.3.

I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Here, you have downloaded source code and tried to open it as a project directly. The error means what it says: you didn't set up your project to depend on any of the libs the library needs, like Android. Instead, you should have imported the Maven build.

But then you say you're adding the core .jar file but from an entirely different version, 3.1.0. What is going on?

Comment: what I am trying to do is importing the ZXing library into Android Studio and then integrating it with my project that I will implement a simple QRCoreScanner. How can I setup this project with library needs?

Comment: Then you do not need to download or build anything. You need the core lib or android-integration libs only. Start your own project.