# Android app implement barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I would like to implement a barcode scanner function in my app.

I found this [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/12/tutorial-65-implement-barcode-scanner-using-zxing-in-android/).

Problem is, that I work with Android studio and not with eclipse.
if I understand this tutorial, I can use the scan function of zxing in my app without installing a third app.

Can anyone explain to me how I can use this function in my app?

Comment: What is your real problem?

Comment: Step 2: Import ZXing Android project

You need to import the ZXing Android project in Eclipse. Once imported right click the Project –> Properties –> Android and tick mark the Is Library checkbox. Also, create a new folder called libs within the project and add the core.jar file. The core.jar can be downloaded from over here.

How i do this import with android studio?

Comment: So your problem is how to import a library into  android studio or how to code with zxing library?

Comment: Related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki: yes

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you one other way. download this project and add [BarCodeScanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)

for opening an bar code scanner on any click event call this capture activity form intent like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

OnActivityResult()

```
onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage") != null) {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data
                        .getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage"));
            }

            if (data.getStringExtra("BarcodeFormate") != null
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data
                    .getStringExtra("BarcodeFormate"))) {
                bBarcodeFormate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bBarcodeFormate.setText("Barcode Formats " + data
                        .getStringExtra("BarcodeFormate"));
            }

            if (data.getStringExtra("Type") != null
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getStringExtra("Type"))) {
                bType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bType.setText("Type " + data.getStringExtra("Type"));
            }

            if (data.getStringExtra("DateFormate") != null
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data
                    .getStringExtra("DateFormate"))) {
                bDateFormate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bDateFormate.setText("Date Formate " + data.getStringExtra("DateFormate"));
            }

            if (data.getStringExtra("MetaData") != null
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getStringExtra("MetaData"))) {
                bmetaDataText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bmetaDataText.setText("MetaData " + data.getStringExtra("MetaData"));
            }

            if (data.getStringExtra("DisplayContents") != null
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data
                    .getStringExtra("DisplayContents"))) {
                dDisplayContents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dDisplayContents.setText("Display Contents " + data
                        .getStringExtra("DisplayContents"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any doubt or issue let me know.

**by this you have no need install third party app for bar code scanner**

Comment: work this code with min. sdk 15?
what do you mean with "add barcode scanner" i have downloaded this files. and now? :(