# Adding Dependency ZXing android embedded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing

I've started a new project in Android Studio and I want to import the zxing-android-embedded to allow to me create a simple barcode scanner within my application.
[Found here on github](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Following instruction on there and also on different sources like this SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23788163/3364482

However I have added the compile optins to my `build.gradle` but I'm getting the "Failed to resolve" errors:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0
>   Failed to resolve: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.3.0
>   Failed to resolve: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.3.0

But as far as I'm aware my buid.gradle is as instructed:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapps.practice.helloworld"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

EDIT: I'm not in Offline Mode.

Comment: Did you appear to be in Offline Mode?

Comment: No, Offline Mode is not ticked. I'm behind a proxy but Check Connection returns successful (In settings).

Comment: I made a commit to this project that works fine, and here is the Gradle file. https://github.com/xuxingliu922/DeviceSDK/blob/master/SmartDeviceSDK/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for that, I notice my BuildTools isn't 'x.x.2' like yours is or the one on the github's project page. Going to upgrade now and see if that works.

Comment: Upgraded buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" but still no avail :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this is the most recent version from git:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'   // Version 23+ is required
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' // Older versions may give compile errors
}
```

Comment: Still get error: Failed to resolve on both. Must have something to do with the proxy..

Answer (score 0):

There is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "space.klapeyron.testqr"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    //added by Klapeyron start
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'   // Version 23+ is required
    //added by Klapeyron end
}

//added by Klapeyron start
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
//added by Klapeyron end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to Upgrade my gradle to 3.4 and use implementation instead of compile:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
   implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
   //...
}
```

You might also need to clear the cache and restart if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle (:app) add:
`implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'`
`implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'` It works for me. Maybe it'll help somebody who get this error in 2019 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have imported it :

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version for 24+ is

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

for the latest version i replaced

```
implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-3.4.0"
```

with:

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
```

and it worked for me

Comment: Will this library support Android 14?