# Create App using ZXing Barcode Scanner To send to pc for Android

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Good day. I have started working on a little project I have. It is sort of complex as I have no real knowledge of creating apps or java script. I would like to start off with how my app will work.

Firstly how I see it, it will be based on a wireless keyboard app. It will have two buttons once opened. One for Syncing with the PC Client using QRcode and the other for scanning barcodes.

Once the Scan Barcodes section button is clicked you will see the ZXing barcode scanning screen shown with a manual input button aswell as a turn on and off flash button.

Once the barcode has been successfully read it will be sent to the synced pc using keystrokes. At the end of the barcode it will insert a TAB character.

Once done with the scan, at the same time a new windows will open asking for you to input the quantity. Once you select done it sends the quantity to the synced pc also using keystrokes ending with a ENTER character. Then it will return back too the Scan Screen.

If the manual input button is pressed it will then open an input box and send the input much like the scanned barcode.

I have tried figuring it out but I cant seem to get ZXing to properly integrate in my app that is still mainly empty and been deleted almost 100 times.

Could someone please help me figure it out. Also please note I am using the latest Android Studio for creating the apps. I tried following this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio) but I keep running into errors and can't figure out what's going wrong. Could someone please just help me get this app up? I don't intend to sell it. I just want to use it for personal use and if successful upload it too the play store.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So after all that background information you are trying to integrate the ZXing library into your Android project - is that your question? What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: To start I cant seam to get it to integrate. I don't really understand how. If someone could provide more info on this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio) I could get it into my app the way I need it

Comment: What parts are you struggling with?

Comment: Use their sample app and see if that works for you? https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/sample

Comment: Okay I got it working using the method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio) but it is not how I want it. I want it in portrait mode and I want it to continue scanning. How can I use the files from the sample [app](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/sample) in my app so I can use the same code

Comment: Not sure but putting this link if it can help you http://nverma-tech-blog.blogspot.in/2017/06/generating-and-reading-qr-code-two.html