# add zxing to build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, zxing

I want to use xzing in android studio. To use that I added a dependency to the app/build.gradle but unfortunally when I sync the Gradle project it produces the following error

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio   does it work?

Comment: no. "Failed to resolve: com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0" and "Failed to resolve: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change in my project-gradle.build-File this:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      //jcenter()
      jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})
   }
}
```

It works :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful, this syncs fine for me in studio (its and old project with older lib but should update fine):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
```