# How to convert a simple string to QR code in Android?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to share a simple string between two android devices with QR code.

For Scanning the code i use google mobile vision API, but what's the best way to generate it?

All libraries that i found such as Zxing are old and no longer maintained.

Comment: Yes, "ZXing" is in "maintenance mode".  But it's not "old"; and it's very good.  I'd encourage you to use it: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: @paulsm4 I said that because most of it's questions are closed and looks like it has a lot of problems. Also I couldn't find a straightforward way to use It. Can you tell me how to import it in android studio with an example please!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578827/421195

Answer (score 0):

You can use library by  [androidmads/QRGenerator](https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator)     Backed by Zxing but continuosly maintainted and support.

### Features:

- QR code color can be changed dynamically

### implementations

```
implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
```

### Creating QR Code from Text

```
QRGEncoder qrgEncoder = new QRGEncoder(inputValue, null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT, smallerDimension);
qrgEncoder.setColorBlack(Color.RED);
qrgEncoder.setColorWhite(Color.BLUE);
try {
     // Getting QR-Code as Bitmap
     bitmap = qrgEncoder.getBitmap();
     // Setting Bitmap to ImageView
     qrImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  } catch (WriterException e) {
     Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
 }
```

### Save QR Code Image

```
QRGSaver qrgSaver = new QRGSaver();
qrgSaver.save(savePath, edtValue.getText().toString().trim(), bitmap, QRGContents.ImageType.IMAGE_JPEG);
```

Comment: smallerDimension is not defined, you should fix that